# Buddypress plugin bug - XML to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml-parsing, wordpress, buddypress

It is an external group blogs plugin

It gives group creators and administrators on your BuddyPress install the ability to attach external blog RSS feeds to groups.
Blog posts will appear within the activity stream for the group.
New posts will automatically be pulled every hour, or every 30 minutes if someone specifically visits a group page.

There are so many bugs that I found.
1) it is not fetching feeds automatically
2) if I try to manually updates feeds it is reposting the same entries, I mean it is not fetching new feeds.
3) WordPress admin bar is also not working properly with this plugin.

This plugin contains 2 webpages.

First and the main page is loader.php

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: External Group Blogs
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/external-group-blogs/
Description: Allow group creators to supply external blog RSS feeds that will attach        future posts on blogs to a group.
*/

 /* Only load the plugin functions if BuddyPress is loaded and initialized. */
function bp_groupblogs_init() {
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/bp-groups-externalblogs.php' );
}
add_action( 'bp_init', 'bp_groupblogs_init' );

/* On activation register the cron to refresh external blog posts. */
function bp_groupblogs_activate() {
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'bp_groupblogs_cron' );
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'bp_groupblogs_activate' );

/* On deacativation, clear the cron. */
function bp_groupblogs_deactivate() {
wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'bp_groupblogs_cron' );

/* Remove all external blog activity */
if ( function_exists( 'bp_activity_delete' ) )
    bp_activity_delete( array( 'type' => 'exb' ) );
}
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'bp_groupblogs_deactivate' );

?>
```

And the 2nd file is bp-groups-externalblogs.php

```
<?php
/* Group blog extension using the BuddyPress group extension API */
if ( class_exists('BP_Group_Extension' ) ) {

class Group_External_Blogs extends BP_Group_Extension {
    function __construct() {
        global $bp;
        $this->name = __( 'External Blogs', 'bp-groups-externalblogs' );
        $this->slug = 'external-blog-feeds';
        $this->create_step_position = 21;
        $this->enable_nav_item = false;
    }
    function create_screen() {
        global $bp;
        if ( !bp_is_group_creation_step( $this->slug ) )
            return false;
        ?>
        <p><?php _e(
            "Add RSS feeds of blogs you'd like to attach to this group in the box below.
             Any future posts on these blogs will show up on the group page and be recorded
             in activity streams.", 'bp-groups-externalblogs' ) ?>
        </p>
        <p class="desc"><?php _e( "Seperate URL's with commas.", 'bp-groups-externalblogs' ) ?></span>
        <p>
            <label for="blogfeeds"><?php _e( "Feed URL's:", 'bp-groups-externalblogs' ) ?></label>
            <textarea name="blogfeeds" id="blogfeeds"><?php echo attribute_escape( implode( ', ', (array)groups_get_groupmeta( $bp->groups->current_group->id, 'blogfeeds' ) ) ) ?></textarea>
        </p>
        <?php
        wp_nonce_field( 'groups_create_save_' . $this->slug );
    }
    function create_screen_save() {
        global $bp;
        check_admin_referer( 'groups_create_save_' . $this->slug );
        $unfiltered_feeds = explode( ',', $_POST['blogfeeds'] );
        foreach( (array) $unfiltered_feeds as $blog_feed ) {
            if ( !empty( $blog_feed ) )
                $blog_feeds[] = trim( $blog_feed );
        }
        groups_update_groupmeta( $bp->groups->current_group->id, 'blogfeeds', $blog_feeds );
        groups_update_groupmeta( $bp->groups->current_group->id, 'bp_groupblogs_lastupdate', gmdate( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ) );
        /* Fetch */
        bp_groupblogs_fetch_group_feeds( $bp->groups->current_group->id );
    }
    function edit_screen() {
        global $bp;
        if ( !bp_is_group_admin_screen( $this->slug ) )
            return false; ?>
        <p class="desc"><?php _e( "Enter RSS feed URL's for blogs you would like to attach to this group. Any future posts on these blogs will show on the group activity stream. Seperate URL's with commas.", 'bp-groups-externalblogs' ) ?></span>
        <p>
            <label for="blogfeeds"><?php _e( "Feed URL's:", 'bp-groups-externalblogs' ) ?></label>
            <textarea name="blogfeeds" id="blogfeeds"><?php echo attribute_escape( implode( ', ', (array)groups_get_groupmeta( $bp->groups->current_group->id, 'blogfeeds' ) ) ) ?></textarea>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="<?php _e( "Update Feed URL's", 'bp-groups-externalblogs' ) ?>" />
        <?php
        wp_nonce_field( 'groups_edit_save_' . $this->slug );
    }
    function edit_screen_save() {
        global $bp;
        if ( !isset( $_POST['save'] ) )
            return false;
        check_admin_referer( 'groups_edit_save_' . $this->slug );
        $existing_feeds = (array)groups_get_groupmeta( $bp->groups->current_group->id, 'blogfeeds' );
        $unfiltered_feeds = explode( ',', $_POST['blogfeeds'] );
        foreach( (array) $unfiltered_feeds as $blog_feed ) {
            if ( !empty( $blog_feed ) )
                $blog_feeds[] = trim( $blog_feed );
        }
        /* Loop and find any feeds that have been removed, so we can delete activity stream items */
        if ( !empty( $existing_feeds ) ) {
            foreach( (array) $existing_feeds as $feed ) {
                if ( !in_array( $feed, (array) $blog_feeds ) )
                    $removed[] = $feed;
            }
        }
        if ( $removed  ) {
            /* Remove activity stream items for this feed */
            include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rss.php' );
            foreach( (array) $removed as $feed ) {
                $rss = fetch_rss( trim( $feed ) );
                if ( function_exists( 'bp_activity_delete' ) ) {
                    bp_activity_delete( array(
                        'item_id' => $bp->groups->current_group->id,
                        'secondary_item_id' => wp_hash( $rss->channel['link'] ),
                        'component' => $bp->groups->id,
                        'type' => 'exb'
                    ) );
                }
            }
        }
        groups_update_groupmeta( $bp->groups->current_group->id, 'blogfeeds', $blog_feeds );
        groups_update_groupmeta( $bp->groups->current_group->id, 'bp_groupblogs_lastupdate', gmdate( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ) );
        /* Re-fetch */
        bp_groupblogs_fetch_group_feeds( $bp->groups->current_group->id );
        bp_core_add_message( __( 'External blog feeds updated successfully!', 'bp-groups-externalblogs' ) );
        bp_core_redirect( bp_get_group_permalink( $bp->groups->current_group ) . '/admin/' . $this->slug );
    }
    /* We don't need display functions since the group activity stream handles it all. */
    function display() {}
    function widget_display() {}
}

bp_register_group_extension( 'Group_External_Blogs' );

function bp_groupblogs_fetch_group_feeds( $group_id = false ) {
    global $bp;
    include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/rss.php' );
    if ( empty( $group_id ) )
        $group_id = $bp->groups->current_group->id;
    if ( $group_id == $bp->groups->current_group->id )
        $group = $bp->groups->current_group;
    else
        $group = new BP_Groups_Group( $group_id );
    if ( !$group )
        return false;
    $group_blogs = groups_get_groupmeta( $group_id, 'blogfeeds' );
    $group_blogs = explode(";",$group_blogs[0]);

    /* Set the visibility */
    $hide_sitewide = ( 'public' != $group->status ) ? true : false;
    foreach ( (array) $group_blogs as $feed_url ) {
        $rss = fetch_feed( trim( $feed_url ) );
        if (!is_wp_error($rss) ) {
            foreach ( $rss->get_items(0,10) as $item ) {;
                $key = $item->get_date( 'U' );
                $items[$key]['title'] = $item->get_title();
                $items[$key]['subtitle'] = $item->get_title();
                //$items[$key]['author'] = $item->get_author()->get_name();
                $items[$key]['blogname'] = $item->get_feed()->get_title();
                $items[$key]['link'] = $item->get_permalink();
                $items[$key]['blogurl'] = $item->get_feed()->get_link();
                $items[$key]['description'] = $item->get_description();
                $items[$key]['source'] = $item->get_source();
                $items[$key]['copyright'] = $item->get_copyright();
            }
        }
    }
    if ( $items ) {
        ksort($items);
        $items = array_reverse($items, true);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    /* Record found blog posts in activity streams */
    foreach ( (array) $items as $post_date => $post ) {
        //var_dump($post);
        if (substr($post['blogname'],0,7) == "Twitter") {
            $activity_action = sprintf( __( '%s from %s in the group %s', 'bp-groups-externalblogs' ), '<a class="feed-link" href="' . esc_attr( $post['link'] ) . '">Tweet</a>', '<a class="feed-author" href="' . esc_attr( $post['blogurl'] ) . '">' . attribute_escape( $post['blogname'] ) . '</a>', '<a href="' . bp_get_group_permalink( $group ) . '">' . attribute_escape( $group->name ) . '</a>' );
        } else {
            $activity_action = sprintf( __( 'Blog: %s from %s in the group %s', 'bp-groups-externalblogs' ), '<a class="feed-link" href="' . esc_attr( $post['link'] ) . '">' . esc_attr( $post['title'] ) . '</a>', '<a class="feed-author" href="' . esc_attr( $post['blogurl'] ) . '">' . attribute_escape( $post['blogname'] ) . '</a>', '<a href="' . bp_get_group_permalink( $group ) . '">' . attribute_escape( $group->name ) . '</a>' );
        }

        $activity_content = '<div>' . strip_tags( bp_create_excerpt( $post['description'], 175 ) ) . '</div>';
        $activity_content = apply_filters( 'bp_groupblogs_activity_content', $activity_content, $post, $group );
        /* Fetch an existing activity_id if one exists. */
        if ( function_exists( 'bp_activity_get_activity_id' ) )
            $id = bp_activity_get_activity_id( array( 'user_id' => false, 'action' => $activity_action, 'component' => $bp->groups->id, 'type' => 'exb', 'item_id' => $group_id, 'secondary_item_id' => wp_hash( $post['blogurl'] ) ) );
        /* Record or update in activity streams. */
        groups_record_activity( array(
            'id' => $id,
            'user_id' => false,
            'action' => $activity_action,
            'content' => $activity_content,
            'primary_link' => $item->get_link(),
            'type' => 'exb',
            'item_id' => $group_id,
            'secondary_item_id' => wp_hash( $post['blogurl'] ),
            'recorded_time' => gmdate( "Y-m-d H:i:s", $post_date ),
            'hide_sitewide' => $hide_sitewide
        ) );
    }
    return $items;
}

/* Add a filter option to the filter select box on group activity pages */
function bp_groupblogs_add_filter() { ?>
    <option value="exb"><?php _e( 'External Blogs', 'bp-groups-externalblogs' ) ?></option><?php
}
add_action( 'bp_group_activity_filter_options', 'bp_groupblogs_add_filter' );
add_action( 'bp_activity_filter_options', 'bp_groupblogs_add_filter' );

/* Add a filter option groups avatar */
/* Fetch group twitter posts after 30 mins expires and someone hits the group page */
function bp_groupblogs_refetch() {
    global $bp;
    $last_refetch = groups_get_groupmeta( $bp->groups->current_group->id, 'bp_groupblogs_lastupdate' );
    if ( strtotime( gmdate( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ) ) >= strtotime( '+30 minutes', strtotime( $last_refetch ) ) )
        add_action( 'wp_footer', 'bp_groupblogs_refetch' );
    /* Refetch the latest group twitter posts via AJAX so we don't stall a page load. */
    function _bp_groupblogs_refetch() {
        global $bp; ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready( function() {
                jQuery.post( ajaxurl, {
                    action: 'refetch_groupblogs',
                    'cookie': encodeURIComponent(document.cookie),
                    'group_id': <?php echo $bp->groups->current_group->id ?>
                });
            });
        </script><?php
        groups_update_groupmeta( $bp->groups->current_group->id, 'bp_groupblogs_lastupdate', gmdate( "Y-m-d H:i:s" ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'groups_screen_group_home', 'bp_groupblogs_refetch' );

/* Refresh via an AJAX post for the group */
function bp_groupblogs_ajax_refresh() {
    bp_groupblogs_fetch_group_feeds( $_POST['group_id'] );
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_refetch_groupblogs', 'bp_groupblogs_ajax_refresh' );

function bp_groupblogs_cron_refresh() {
    global $bp, $wpdb;
    $group_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT group_id FROM " . $bp->groups->table_name_groupmeta . " WHERE meta_key = 'blogfeeds'" ) );
    foreach( $group_ids as $group_id )
        bp_groupblogs_fetch_group_feeds( $group_id );
}
add_action( 'bp_groupblogs_cron', 'bp_groupblogs_cron_refresh' );
}

// Add a filter option groups avatar
function bp_groupblogs_avatar_type($var) {
global $activities_template, $bp;

if ( $activities_template->activity->type == "exb" ) {
    return 'group';
} else {
    return $var;
}
}
add_action( 'bp_get_activity_avatar_object_groups', 'bp_groupblogs_avatar_type');
add_action( 'bp_get_activity_avatar_object_activity', 'bp_groupblogs_avatar_type');

function bp_groupblogs_avatar_id($var) {
global $activities_template, $bp;

if ( $activities_template->activity->type == "exb" ) {
    return $activities_template->activity->item_id;
}

return $var;

}
add_action( 'bp_get_activity_avatar_item_id', 'bp_groupblogs_avatar_id');

?>
```

I have a suggestion for stopping data repeating in activity stream. Maybe use wp-cron api and a current date xml feeds fetching system once in a day. So it will not repeat the same feeds in a group activity stream. We need a criteria by which we can stop data repetition in the bp group activity stream. It is a part of my project. Is there another way of fetching feeds and saving it to the mysql table (in the group activity stream) and then show it as a latest group updates?

Comment: We had similar issues with buddy media. Know what we did to fix it? We stopped using buddy media.

Comment: He he..But i need this plugin.. There is no alternate of this plugin on buddypress

Comment: You have to be more specific with your question. If there is a question at all.. This is not the place where other programmers do the job for you, sorry.

Comment: I know that but i am just ask for a little help,..If i was to fix it then i will never post it here..

Comment: I was trying to solve the exact same problem. Which is how I found this question. I have no idea why it is not updating the group feed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually IT IS fetching automatically.
I see the cron usage in a plugin. WordPress Cron fires only when any user opens your site. So no users (no pageviews) - no cron activity. On every pageview WP-Cron check whether the time to fire any function came or not.

Perhaps [this plugin](https://github.com/slaFFik/bp-groups-rss-feed-tab) will help you a bit - display a RSS feed in a separate group tab.

Comment: This is very good plugin but there is problem..I want to rss feeds updates in my group activity stream then users will be able to like, comment or favorite it on posted feeds. That is needed. Can you add that.. but anyway it is a good script

Comment: Your plugin is not saving data from rss it is just fetching feeds in a real time and showing them in the group rss tab.. pagination is also not working...see this http://www.coolguruji.com/groups/hollywood/rss-posts/

Comment: No pagination perhaps because only 10 items in rss feed - nothing more to show. Not saving - yes, it was initial feature.

Comment: Anyway, the plugin is rather old and was not even released to WordPress plugins repository - because it's incomplete.

Comment: Okay..But it is a good plugin. I think you must update it bcoz their is no workable plugin available in the buddypress for showing rss feeds from external sources..I have checked hole plugin directory of buddypress.. all of them are containing bugs and they outdated. @slaFFik

Comment: Okay, I will think about this. Currently I'm working with BuddyPress Groups Extras (group fields and pages). After finishing the current version I might spend some time working with RSS for groups.

Comment: Thanks for considering about it.. Please do not forget to tell me if you update it.